# Computing the Variance of The Number of Descents of a Permutation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, expected-value, variance

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $\sigma: [n] \longrightarrow [n]$ be a random permutation in $S_n$, the set of all permutations, and let $d(\sigma)$ be the number of descents of $\sigma$ defined by the cardinality of the set $\{ i \in [n-1] \;| \;\sigma(i+1) < \sigma(i)\}$. Give a closed form expression for the variance of $d(\sigma)$.

My approach thus far: Let $X$ be the random variable denoting the number of descents, and let us express it as the sum of indiator random variables. That is, $X = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_{n-1}$. We have that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{V}(X) &= \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}(X)^2 \\
&= \mathbb{E}(XX) - \mathbb{E}(X)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1, j=1}^{n-1} \mathbb{E}(X_iX_j) - \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\mathbb{E} (X_i)\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \mathbb{E}(X_j)\right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1, j=1}^{n-1} \mathbb{E}(X_i X_j) - \mathbb{E}(X_i)\mathbb{E}(X_j)
\end{align*}
It looks like we obtain a sum of covariances for muliple pairs of $X_i$'s. Nonetheless, this is where I got stuck because I am not sure how to proceed from here. It would be easier if the $X_i$'s were independent and identically distributed, but it is not the case. I would truly appreciate any help on computing this variance!

Comment: Have you computed $P(X_i=1)$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ fixed?

Comment: This is actually the point that confused me. To me it seems like there is no easy way to compute this probability because of the dependence of the indicator random variables. How can I compute that ?

Comment: Note $X_i=1 \iff \sigma(i+1)<\sigma(i)$ and $X_i=0$ otherwise. I'm thinking of using the total law of probability... $$P(X_i=1)=\sum_{k=1}^nP(X_i=1|\sigma(i)=k)P(\sigma(i)=k)=\sum_{k=1}^n\Bigg(\frac{k-1}{n-1}\cdot\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}\Bigg)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: We can also get this with a counting argument. $$P(X_i=1)=P(\sigma(i)>\sigma(i+1))=\frac{{n \choose 2}(n-2)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $i\in[n-1]$ let $X_i=1 \iff \sigma(i+1)>\sigma(i)$ and $X_i=0$ otherwise. Put $$X=X_1 + \dots + X_{n-1}$$
As you said, $X$ counts the number of descents in your random permutation. We need to compute $V(X)$ which we'll express as $$V(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}V(X_k)+2\sum_{i<j}\text{cov}(X_i,X_j)$$ Notice  $V(X_1)=V(X_i)$ and $\text{cov}(X_1,X_2)=\text{cov}(X_i,X_{i+1})$. Moreover $\text{cov}(X_1,X_3)=\text{cov}(X_i,X_j)$ for $i,j\in[n-1]$ such that $j-i>1$. Since there are $n-1$ terms in the first sum and $n-2$ out of ${n-1 \choose 2}$ terms of the form $\text{cov}(X_i,X_{i+1})$ in the second sum, we can further simply $V(X)$ into the following expression: $$V(X)=(n-1)V(X_1)+2(n-2)\text{cov}(X_1,X_2)+(n-2)(n-3)\text{cov}(X_1,X_3)$$ With a little counting we see that $$P(X_1=1)=\frac{{n \choose 2}(n-2)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{2} \\ P(X_1=1,X_2=1)=\frac{{n \choose 3}(n-3)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{6} \\ P(X_1=1,X_3=1)=\frac{{n \choose 2}{n-2 \choose 2}(n-4)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{4}$$ Using these values we obtain $V(X_1)=\frac{1}{4},\text{cov}(X_1,X_2)=-\frac{1}{12},$ and $\text{cov}(X_1,X_3)=0$. Putting everything together, we finally get $V(X)=\frac{n+1}{12}$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response!